# Custom Tokenizer, Iterator with quotes

Tags: java, text, iterator, token

Maybe some one can help?
How to modify this method next() that the next token can be: 'abc' text with the quotes.
Now if the text contains quote are throwed ExpressionException Unknown operator ''' at position...

```
 @Override
    public String next() {
        StringBuilder token = new StringBuilder();
        if (pos >= input.length()) {
            return previousToken = null;
        }
        char ch = input.charAt(pos);
        while (Character.isWhitespace(ch) && pos < input.length()) {
            ch = input.charAt(++pos);
        }
        if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
            while ((Character.isDigit(ch) || ch == decimalSeparator)
                    && (pos < input.length())) {
                token.append(input.charAt(pos++));
                ch = pos == input.length() ? 0 : input.charAt(pos);
            }
        } else if (ch == minusSign
                && Character.isDigit(peekNextChar())
                && ("(".equals(previousToken) || ",".equals(previousToken)
                        || previousToken == null || operators
                        .containsKey(previousToken))) {
            token.append(minusSign);
            pos++;
            token.append(next());
        } else if (Character.isLetter(ch)) {
            while ((Character.isLetter(ch) || Character.isDigit(ch) || (ch == '_')) && (pos < input.length())) {
                token.append(input.charAt(pos++));
                ch = pos == input.length() ? 0 : input.charAt(pos);
            }
            } else if (ch == '(' || ch == ')' || ch == ',') {
                token.append(ch);
                pos++;
                //FIXME
            else if (ch == '\''){

                pos++;
                String temp = "\'"+next()+"\'";
                token.append(temp);
                pos++;

            }
            //        

} else {
                while (!Character.isLetter(ch) && !Character.isDigit(ch)
                        && !Character.isWhitespace(ch) && ch != '('
                        && ch != ')' && ch != ',' && (pos < input.length())) {
                    token.append(input.charAt(pos));
                    pos++;
                    ch = pos == input.length() ? 0 : input.charAt(pos);
                    if (ch == minusSign) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (!operators.containsKey(token.toString())) {
                    throw new ExpressionException("Unknown operator '" + token
                            + "' at position " + (pos - token.length() + 1));
                }
            }
            return previousToken = token.toString();
        }
```

**eval**

```
public Object eval() {

    Stack<Object> stack = new Stack<Object>();

    for (String token : getRPN()) {
        mylog.pl("Reverse polish notation TOKEN : " + token + " RPN size: " + getRPN().size() );
        if (operators.containsKey(token)) {
            Object v1 = stack.pop();
            Object v2 = stack.pop();
            stack.push(operators.get(token).eval(v2, v1));
        } else if (variables.containsKey(token)) {
            stack.push(variables.get(token).round(mc));
        } else if (functions.containsKey(token.toUpperCase())) {
            Function f = functions.get(token.toUpperCase());
            ArrayList<Object> p = new ArrayList<Object>(f.getNumParams());
            for (int i = 0; i < f.numParams; i++) {
                p.add(0, stack.pop());
            }
            Object fResult = f.eval(p);
            stack.push(fResult);
        } else if (isDate(token)) {
            Long date = null;
            try {
                date = SU.sdf.parse(token).getTime();
            } catch (ParseException e) {/* IGNORE! */
            }
            stack.push(new BigDecimal(date, mc));
        } else {
            if (BusinessStrategy.PREFIX_X.equals(Character.toString(token.charAt(0)))) {
                stack.push(token);
            } else {
                stack.push(new BigDecimal(token, mc));
            }
        }
    }
    return stack.pop();
}
```

**Reverse notation**

```
    private List<String> getRPN() {
    if (rpn == null) {
        rpn = shuntingYard(this.expression);
    }
    return rpn;
}
```

**Yard**

```
    private List<String> shuntingYard(String expression) {
    List<String> outputQueue = new ArrayList<String>();
    Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();

    Tokenizer tokenizer = new Tokenizer(expression);

    String lastFunction = null;
    while (tokenizer.hasNext()) {
        String token = tokenizer.next();
        if (isNumber(token)) {
            outputQueue.add(token);                     
        } else if (variables.containsKey(token)) {
            outputQueue.add(token);
        } else if (functions.containsKey(token.toUpperCase())) {
            stack.push(token);
            lastFunction = token;
        } else if (Character.isLetter(token.charAt(0))) {
            if ("\'".equals(Character.toString(token.charAt(0)))){
                outputQueue.add(token);                    
            } else {
                stack.push(token);                    
            }
        } else if (",".equals(token)) {
            while (!stack.isEmpty() && !"(".equals(stack.peek())) {
                outputQueue.add(stack.pop());
            }
            if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                throw new ExpressionException("Parse error for function '"
                        + lastFunction + "'");
            }
        } else if (operators.containsKey(token)) {
            Operator o1 = operators.get(token);
            String token2 = stack.isEmpty() ? null : stack.peek();
            while (operators.containsKey(token2)
                    && ((o1.isLeftAssoc() && o1.getPrecedence() <= operators
                            .get(token2).getPrecedence()) || (o1
                            .getPrecedence() < operators.get(token2)
                            .getPrecedence()))) {
                outputQueue.add(stack.pop());
                token2 = stack.isEmpty() ? null : stack.peek();
            }
            stack.push(token);
        } else if ("(".equals(token)) {
            stack.push(token);
        } else if (")".equals(token)) {
            while (!stack.isEmpty() && !"(".equals(stack.peek())) {
                outputQueue.add(stack.pop());
            }
            if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Mismatched parentheses");
            }
            stack.pop();
            if (!stack.isEmpty()
                    && functions.containsKey(stack.peek().toUpperCase())) {
                outputQueue.add(stack.pop());
            }
        }
    }
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        String element = stack.pop();
        if ("(".equals(element) || ")".equals(element)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Mismatched parentheses");
        }
        if (!operators.containsKey(element)) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unknown operator or function: "
                    + element);
        }
        outputQueue.add(element);
    }
    return outputQueue;
}
```

**Error**

```
*java.util.EmptyStackException
    at java.util.Stack.peek(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Stack.pop(Unknown Source)
    at com.business.Expression.eval(Expression.java:1033)*
```

It is in eval method    `Object v1 = stack.pop();` line.

Thanks !

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, **a specific problem or error** and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce it** in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Desired behavior is that tokenizer example above can return varchar token: quote + text + quote .

Comment: Please add the **full stack trace** to you question together with the **rest** of your code. From the link above **Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem**

Comment: I've no idea what your code is trying to do, but why are you trying to `pop()` from an empty `stack`? That is for you to work out ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In method `next` you have recursive calls in two places:

1. after seeing a minus sign
2. after recognizing an apostrope

The first situation will construct tokens where a minus is followed by a digit (i.e., an unsigend number follows) - OK. (Although, not having a sign but an unary minus operator deserves some consideration.)

The second scenario means trouble. After advancing past the initial apostrophe, another next-result is expected, as if string literals would only contain one number or one identifier or a single operator. Anyway, the next() executes, let's say it returns a number: then an apostroph is added to the token, but there's no effort to check whether there is a closing apostrophe nor to skip that.

```
 else if (ch == '\''){
     token.append( '\'' );
     pos++;
     while( pos < input.length() &&
            (ch = input.charAt(pos++)) != '\'' ){
         token.append( ch );
     }
     token.append( '\'' );
```

This doesn't permit an apostrophe to be a character within the string and it does not diagnose an unterminated string. But this can be added rather easily.